# Can't access Eduroam wireless internet connection SETTINGS (Linux Mint 17)

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, settings

Using Linux Mint (Cinnamon Desktop) I have not been able to connect to the [eduroam](https://www.eduroam.org) wireless university network. The reason is that I can't find a proper way to enter the respective network settings, i.e. changing security settings as well as filling in my account name and password.

This is what I get (apologies for the Dutch language):
[image]

As you can see, some other networks (in this case: UU visitor) let me change settings if I want to. 
**edit: it does not prompt me for the settings when I try to connect to the network**

How can I access the settings of any network which does not provide the settings icon? Or if you happen to be an expert on eduroam, how can I access that network specifically?

Comment: If you try to connect to eduroam it does not prompt you for the settings/credentials? Some of these graphical wizard tools may not have a so visible way to configure a network you have never used, but they will ask for the settings the first time you try to connect to it.

Comment: @njsg Oh, I should have added that for clarity: no, it does not prompt me for the settings/credentials. 
If you have a suggestion about how to make that prompt appear, it would be great :)

Comment: I have the same problem with the new network manager :/

Comment: Just FTR for those not familiar with eduroam, it uses 802.1X + EAP.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Linux Mint (since 17.1)<sup>1</sup> and followed [this](http://www.utwente.nl/icts/en/handleidingen/netwerk/mac_linux/eduroam%20voor%20Ubuntu/) guide which was working for me, so far.

(Please leave a comment if this is working for other LM releases as well so that I can update this answer)

What I did in a nutshell..

Started the **Network Connections**<sup>2</sup> app:

[image]
Added a new Wi-Fi network connection:

[image]
[image]
Entered the following credentials:

[image]
[image]

I think that was it.

---

<sup>1 As comments indicate/confirm, this should also work with the following OS versions: 17.2, 18.0, 18.1 and 18.3</sup>

<sup>2 Note: Make sure you open "Network Connections" instead of "Network"</sup>

Comment: Nope :( this only works in 17.1 with the old network manager... Not in 17.2

Comment: That's unfortunate...is 17.1 and 17.2 really that different?

Comment: Apart from that, could you provide some more information what exactly is going wrong, i.e. describe you're exact use case scenario etc..

Comment: @Lukasstr Have you tried [those](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap) workarounds?

Comment: @JimMcAdams I tried the above suggestions as well, but it didn't work for me either. 17.2 just doesn't allow for adding a connection though the network settings. Is there any way of adding a network through the terminal maybe? 
And what do you mean with case scenario?

Comment: @Lena So when you open the 'Network Connections' app (2nd pic above) Then the 'Add' button is greyed out? Or when you've added a new connection, the 'Edit' button is greyed out? Or does the 'Network Connections' doesn't even appear? You might want to start the app with `sudo nm-connection-editor` then but I don't think it's gonna help much... It seems however that [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/cant-connect-to-wpa2-enterprise-peap) problem on AskUbuntu is the same as yours so I expect the answers apply to you as well... Let me know if it works.

Comment: Worked for me on linux mint cinnamon 17.3. Left the "CA certificate" blank and ignored the warnings regarding that (do this at your own risk).

Comment: Worked also on Linux Mint 18.1 for TU Delft eduroam.

Comment: "Mode: Infrastructure" doesn't exist for me in the drop down list of image 4. I can choose between: client, hotspot, ad-hoc. Linux Mint 19.

Comment: Update: using "client" worked.

Answer (score 7):

If you go to https://cat.eduroam.org/ you can select your university and it will download a script.

One reason that you may want to use the script is because it will download the right CA.  I tried the previous answers before trying the script and it appeared that the previous did not work because my institution uses the digicert root.

From the terminal (after downloading from Chrome) I did:

1. `cd ~/Downloads`
2. `chmod +x eduroam-linux-USU.sh` (change this to the script for your university)
3. `./eduroam-linux-USU.sh` (again, change the script name to the one you downloaded)
4. Follow the on screen prompts
5. You should now be able to connect

*Note:* This is the official Eduroam script and not some 3rd party script.  That is, it was designed by the company that is providing Eduroam access.  On that note, they are probably not looking to do anything malicious.

I did look at the script for some people's security concerns and though I'm not well versed in shell scripts it looks like what it does the following:

- Creates a directory named ".cat_installer" in your home folder
- Adds a certificate named ca.crt to ".cat_installer" directory
- Adds a PFX file cnamed "user.p12" to the ".cat_installer" directory
- Adds network settings for Eduroam including: ssid, key_mgmt, pairwise,group, eap, ca_cert, identity, subject_match, phase2, and password
- Tries to remove any previous networks defined as eduroam

Comment: I feel it would be a good idea to include a summary of what the script does (because you've checked that before running it, right?) if you're posting an answer like this. Encouraging people to just download a script from somewhere and run it makes the inner security maniac inside me want to scream.

Comment: @Erathiel I did not check it, it is from Eduroam itself and not some shady third-party.  I have checked it now and have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eduroam, hence the confusion :) Thank you for updating your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately after executing the official script and completing the prompt I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed LinuxMint 17.2 on a Dell Latitude E5520, and above instructions were found correct for connecting to eduroam (Erasmus University Rotterdam); Make sure you open "Network Connections" instead of "Network";
Also, after adding the "eduroam" Wifi network, on the Wireless networking page a "Preferences" button appears next to the eduroam network.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @travis-pessetto 's answer to the question "[Can't access Eduroam wireless internet connection SETTINGS (Linux Mint 17)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215870/cant-access-eduroam-wireless-internet-connection-settings-linux-mint-17/228852#228852)", I thought it was worthwhile to note that the [CAT eduroam installer](https://cat.eduroam.org/) only worked for me with root privileges: `sudo ./eduroam-linux-<your_institution>.sh`